# LWC datatable column width responsive

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a LWC component (NOT Aura) that has a datatable with just one column.

By default, the width of that column is 1000 px, which is way too small.

Using `max-column-width="4000"` or similar on the `lightning-datatable` tag i can get the column to size itself to screen width.

However, if the user then resizes the screen, the column does not follow that.

Is there any way to set the column to be 100% width rather than a fixed value in pixels?

As requested, here's the code which is absolutely vanilla...

```
 <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns} is-loading={loading} max-column-width="4000">
        </lightning-datatable>
```

Js file:

```
@track data = [{ Id: '1', Name: 'test', link: '/somewhere/else' }];
@track loading = false;
    columns = [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'link', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {
            label: { fieldName: 'Name' }
          } }
    ];
```

Comment: can you paste the code here?

Comment: @rahulgawale sure but it doesn't help at all.

Comment: did you find a solution to that? facing the same issue

Comment: @DanaGriff it just started working; it is not really responsive in that you can see it redraw, but it works. I changed nothing and highly suspected that one fo the patches to LWC that SF deployed did that.

Answer (score 2):

for me it solved with following css

```
.datatable-full-size {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

And in the html side

```
<lightning-datatable class="datatable-full-size" key-field="Id" columns={columnsSolutions} data={solutionsList}></lightning-datatable>
```